# Do any token extensions provide a token for "age" rather than just DOB?

Tags: contacts, tokens, message-templates

Age is displayed on a contact record but only DOB is a token available in message templates.

Are there any extensions that make age available for use? I've not been able to locate anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounded like a useful feature, so I added Age tokens to Eileen's [CiviTokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) extension, which seems to be the most widely used extension of its kind. Until a new release comes out, you'll have to pull from the [master branch of the git repo](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Pulling shortly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any either, but the code to use in such an extension (as either a token or even a smarty modifier) seems pretty straightforward:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.19.2/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php#L2677-L2684

```
      if ($contact->birth_date) {
        $birthDate = CRM_Utils_Date::customFormat($contact->birth_date, '%Y%m%d');
        if ($birthDate < date('Ymd')) {
          $age = CRM_Utils_Date::calculateAge($birthDate);
          $values['age']['y'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('years', $age);
          $values['age']['m'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('months', $age);
        }
      }
```